# Pass a variabile from php to js via JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

At the lessons i learn how to pass result from a sql request to js via JSON/AJAX. I need the value of the row from this request in my js but it doesnt work. Via console i have an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

part of PHP:

```
<?php
//get all the course from db and reply using json structure
//connection to db
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_hyp");
$id = $_POST['id'];
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { //verify connection
    exit(); //do nothing else 
}
else {


    # extract results mysqli_result::fetch_array
    $query = " SELECT * FROM course WHERE course_category='$id'";
    //query execution
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    //if there are data available
    if($result->num_rows >0)
    {
        $myArray = array();//create an array
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
        }
        $response = array();        
        $response['rows'] = $row;
        $response['query'] =  $myArray;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    //free result
    $a=num_rows;
    $result,$a->close();

    //close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}



?>
```

first part of Script:

```
 $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         //dataType: "json", //type of data
         crossDomain: true, //localhost purposes

         url: "./query/cate_has_courses.php", //Relative or absolute path to file.php file
         data: {id: i},
         success: function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response));
             var course=JSON.parse(response.query);
             var row=JSON.parse(response.rows);
```

Comment: This looks like a general syntax error - we'd need more of the PHP file to be sure. Try just navigating to the PHP independently, and see if it's starting with a "<" or some other characters are in there before the JSON. If so, search your doc for stray characters outside <?php tags.

Comment: No... everything it's okay...

Comment: Syntax error: `,$a->close();`. Also `$a=num_rows;` is probably wrong, unless you meant to reference some constant called num_rows.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you use JSON.parse in wrong way. 
The JSON.parse must be done one time only.  The result of JSON.parse is store in course the the access to the data is due by response.query or respons.row .. and so on and not by JSON.parse(respose.query)